# Player dosent seem to get registered into Arraylist

Tags: bukkit

I am having this issue that when my countdown gets to 0 and there are no players on the other team, the team that the player is on wins. But this isnt the case, both teams win when the countdown is 0. How come?

Countdown class:

```
for(Player all2 : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {

            if(main.innocent.size() == 0) {
                Bukkit.broadcastMessage(Main.prefix + "§c§lTRAITORS §6has won the game with all innocents eliminated.");
                GameState.setGamestate(GameState.RESTARTING);

                TitleManager.sendTitle(all2, "§cGame. §c§lOVER!", "§eThanks for playing!", 40);

                for(Player all : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
                    all.getInventory().clear();
                }
            }

            if(main.traitor.size() == 0) {
                Bukkit.broadcastMessage(Main.prefix + "§a§lINNOCENTS §6has won the game with all traitors eliminated.");
                GameState.setGamestate(GameState.RESTARTING);

                TitleManager.sendTitle(all2, "§cGame. §c§lOVER!", "§eThanks for playing!", 40);


            }
```

Arraylist class:

```
public static ArrayList<String> innocent = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> traitor = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to understand what your asking. As mentioned in the comments if its an issue with adding players to the ArrayLists then you need to show us that code.

As for the code you have posted, its rather inefficient. Try changing it to this

```
//Check if your countdown is 0 first? I don't have your class... can't help
if(main.innocent.size() == 0){
    Bukkit.broadcastMessage("Traitor win message");
    GameState.setGamestate(GameState.RESTARTING);
}else if(main.traitor.size() == 0){
    Bukkit.broadcastMessage("Innocent win message");
    GameState.setGamestate(GameState.RESTARTING);
}
...
if(GameState.isRestarting()){ //again, i dont have your class, you'll have to change this
    for(Player p : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()){
        TitleManager.sendTitle(all2, "§cGame. §c§lOVER!", "§eThanks for playing!", 40);
        p.getInventory().clear();
    }
}
```

That should stop both teams from winning, and get rid of the chat spam that the previous code seemed to produce. If you are able to get the rest of the code to me, I will be more than happy to help further.